# Declaring a variable without const vs with const - Test Question

Tags: c++

FYI: This is merely an opinionated question I am looking to find others opinion on.

This was an [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lew5K.png) to one of my Exams in my Computer Science class. Just so you know this was our first test and and the language used in the class is explicitly C++. If you click on the link to the image above you will see the question telling me that there are syntax errors, and that I am to write the acceptable code to make it work. The answer I put for the question was "double x;". Apparently this was incorrect, and I was supposed to "assume that final meant I needed to put const there". Now, truly, I understand my teachers logic in the fact that const does work, but there's nothing in the question stating anything regarding constants or to make the variable a constant. Regardless, both answers should be acceptable.

The purpose of me writing this was to find a sense of, "Am i just wrong?", or do you guys agree that obviously this should be correct?

Btw, in case you're wondering, this was not in a section where the instructions meant constants, or any mention of the word constant on the whole test. This was merely supposed to be intuition of some sort.

Comment: Opinion based questions are explicitly off topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's "obvious" if you're coming from Java, where `final` is used to declare constants.

Comment: This is a question to ask your instructors and your classmates, not for StackOverflow. Personally, I would say the test question is silly if it doesn't tell you the original intent and the expected behavior. It amounts to reading the mind of somebody who can't program correctly, and I would deny that there's a single correct answer

Comment: @melpomene Exactly, but assuming that none of us have ever learned java, final is just a random set of characters in front of the double that will cause it not to compile. It's ridiculous to assume we should know that.

Comment: @alterigel I did ask my teacher and my classmates, I was seeing what the online opinion had to offer.

Comment: I mean, at this point, you could have just `std::cout << "x = 54.3"`. Edit : The fact that the question asks for "**The** correct/acceptable code" tries to imply that there is only one way to write correct and acceptable code to achieve the goal, which is entirely incorrect.

Comment: Syntax error suggests to me that you should fix the syntax, and the way to do this would be exactly what you did which is to remove the offending code which happens to be that `final` keyword

Comment: a program without syntax errors and a correct program are two different and unrelated things. Removing syntax errors is easy. Writing a correct program requires you to know what a program is intended to do, and is harder.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I agree with you there. Regardless of "Best practice" it is a correct answer and deserving of full credit. Not to mention you don't always want your variables as const's, so this could have just as easily BEEN the best practice. There's not enough code to go off of to decide.

Comment: @austintice Best practices for c++ almost unanimously include const correctness. In this case (*assuming the code shown is the entire body of the function*) `const` is warranted.

Comment: @austintice "full credit" is decided by your instructor and their grading rubrik. We on StackOverflow can't change that, nor can we ask your instructor to reconsider their grading. But you can :-)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I understand your point; however, you're so focused on the fact that this MUST be a constant, but disregarding that "double x", like you said, is a correct answer. It's impossible to know what exactly what the code is "supposed to do" when there's only 3 lines, but I know for sure that both ways are "acceptable code".

Comment: Also, @alterigel I understand where full credit is due, and am not asking you for that lol. Just seeking sanity on this very poorly written question.

Comment: In my eyes it's an unreasonable exam question, with an unreasonable correct answer.  It only requires you to correct syntax errors.  It then prompts you to provide "acceptable" code, which is pretty subjective.  The expected answer requires knowledge of Java.  It also is not clear whether the `std` namespace has been imported or not, or correct headers, or a `main`...  so it's not even a MCVE.  It calls itself a "program", despite being only a code snippet without context.

Comment: @paddy I couldn't agree more. There's so much nuance in this question and so much is left to chance.

Comment: the question is as silly as asking to continue the sequence `3 5 7 ...`. Anybody who claims that there is a unique solution is an idiot (in the literal meaning of the word). Try to convey this to your teacher or just get over it, your choice ;)

Answer (score 2):

"final" marks virtual member functions such that they must not be overridden in subclasses, but it is not legal for variables or data members. Hence, the main syntax error I see is the illegal use of `final` together with the variable;

The program has a syntax error, and one can just guess what the writer of the program really intended. And - as it is guessing - I'd say each valid guess that you can argue should be accepted.

Answer (score -2):

You learned something. Your professor is nitpicky about RAII and const correctness.

You now know that, moving forward, in this class, any variable that is not modified (even if it could be later after a refactor) has to be const. Put everything const, always and remove const when needed.

You also know that you should never, for this class, have a declaration without an initialization.

Follow those principles and you'll be ahead of the class in the final exam. Those are good principles. Maybe the professor is a bit heavy handed in their applications. But hey, you're not going to change him/her.

Comment: First, `const` correctness is always desirable. It's not something that should be recommended *just for this class*. Second, we don't know that every declaration should be initialized, just that in this case it was meant to be `const` so necessitated an initializer. Third, opinion based questions should not be answers as they are off topic.

Comment: Agreed on first and last point, but could'nt resist answering anyway. And I mentionned those being good principles in general....

Comment: downvoted for sloppyness. There are good reasons to declare something that needs not be modified as `const` or to prefer initializing always. Imho "being ahead of the class" is not one of them. Following principles without knowing why leads to cargo cult programming.